# Xamarin Forms and Prism, get the name of the View that the ViewModel belongs to?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Xamarin.Forms and Prism 6.3.0
Is there a way from the ViewModel to get the name of the View that the ViewModel belongs to? (In the constructor of the ViewModel perhaps)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish. Your ViewModel should never know anything about the View.

Comment: From the current page, there is a possibility to go to 2 different pages. I have a method (GetNextPage) that takes as a parameter the current page and depending on some logic the method will return the correct page that the application needs to go to.
It’s not that important. I can just pass the name as a string since from the ViewModel, I know the current page. But I will prefer if I was able to make the navigation in a more “generic” way.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is that you're trying to combine two different practices that aren't meant to play together... you shouldn't have code behind in your View that handles anything relating to Navigation, that would be handled in your ViewModel. You should be handling the event with a command not a event handler in your code behind.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn’t actually understood. I have a navigation command in my ViewModel. From that navigation command I can navigate to 2 different views depending on some conditions. One of the conditions is the current view. In my ViewModel, I know the name of the view and I can pass it as a “hard coded” string.. and problem solved. I was looking for a more generic way. And the question still remains, is there a way to get the name of the view from the ViewModel?

Comment: Can you share some code to show people what you're doing.

Comment: `private async void NavigationCommand()
{
 await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(GetNextPage(currentPage), null, true);
}` the currentpage variable is the name of the current View